# How to remove row of data gridview in vb.net?

Tags: html, sql, vb.net

I want to remove the rows of data gridview after use a query sql from database 
i use this code

```
Try
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")

        Dim strConn As String
        strConn = "DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;UID=postgres;Password=azerty79;DATABASE=" & ComboBox2.Text & ";pwd=postgres;ReadOnly=0"
        'strConn = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};UID=postgres;pwd=postgres;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;UseServerSidePrepare=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=0;"

        'strConn = "dsn=test;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres"



        Dim cnDb As OdbcConnection
        Dim dsDB As New DataSet
        Dim adDb As OdbcDataAdapter
        Dim cbDb As OdbcCommandBuilder
        Dim cmd As OdbcCommand
        Dim cmd1 As OdbcCommand
        Dim adDb1 As OdbcDataAdapter
        Dim dsDB1 As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim pic As New PictureBox




        cnDb = New OdbcConnection(strConn)
        cnDb.Open()
        dsDB = New DataSet
        adDb = New OdbcDataAdapter
        cbDb = New OdbcCommandBuilder(adDb)


        'cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.NVarChar, "1")



        For i = 1 To 3


            ' Create the SelectCommand.

            cmd = New OdbcCommand("select b.id_detail_polygon,b.mappe_3,b.type_d_affaire,b.consistance,b.nbr_borne ,num_bornes,a.x,a.y,b.superficie_cs  from point a right join (select (dp).path[1] d1,(dp).path[2] d2,(dp).geom d3 from (select st_dumppoints(geom) dp from polygon where id_detail_polygon ='" & i & "')a)dptable on st_equals(a.geom,dptable.d3),polygon b where id_detail_polygon='" & i & "'", cnDb) ' & _
            '"WHERE id = ? ", cnDb)
            cmd1 = New OdbcCommand("SELECT num_bornes,x,y FROM point RIGHT JOIN  (SELECT (dp).path[1] As ringID,(dp).path[2] As pointID,(dp).geom ptgeom FROM (SELECT st_dumppoints(geom) dp FROM polygon WHERE id_detail_polygon='" & i & "' ) a) dptable ON  ST_Equals(point.geom, dptable.ptgeom) ORDER BY dptable.pointID;", cnDb)
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.NVarChar, "1")


            adDb = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
            adDb1 = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd1)



            adDb.Fill(dsDB, ComboBox1.Text)
            adDb1.Fill(dsDB1, ComboBox1.Text)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB
            DataGridView3.DataSource = dsDB1



            DataGridView2.DataMember = ComboBox1.Text
            DataGridView3.DataMember = ComboBox1.Text
            DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB.DefaultViewManager
            DataGridView3.DataSource = dsDB1.DefaultViewManager





            Dim StrExport As String = ""



            For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows

                For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
                    If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                        StrExport &= C.Value.ToString & " "
                    Else

                    End If
                Next
                StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
                StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
            Next














            Dim fName As String = ""
            SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\"
            SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "dat files (*.dat)|*.dat"
            SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
            SaveFileDialog1.Title = "dat"
            SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
            If (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                fName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
            End If

            For j = 0 To 0
                For x = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1

                    Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(fName)
                    tw.Write(DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value & vbCr & vbLf & DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value & vbCr & vbLf & DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value & vbCr & vbLf & DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value & vbCr & vbLf & DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(4).Value & vbCr & vbLf & StrExport & "       " & DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(8).Value)



                    tw.Close()


                Next

            Next

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row)
            Next

        Next





    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR :" + ex.Message)
    End Try
    MsgBox("Exported", vbInformation, "Successful")
```

But i get this problem below

[image]

Comment: If you cant be bothered to translate the error or event type it in so we can paste it into a translator, why should anyone bother to help?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Basing on your comment, I understand you don't want the data gone from the database bug instead from the grid. I would advise against using a dataset as you have done. A `DataSet` has a collection of `DataTable` objects that you can manipulate. I also see that you are removing every row in a `For Each` loop. You can remove these rows from the table or call the clear method on that table and you grid should reflect it. I have left the original answer to explain why this was happening. **Edit**

Without being able to tell what the error is, I'll just tell you that you cannot programmatically remove a row from a `DataGridView` if the `DataSource` is not an IBindingList with change event notification. OdbcDataAdapter does not implement IBindingList anywhere in its inheritance chain.

If you are not willing to change what you bind to, you can re-run the query to get the items and bind the grid again.

Comment: I don't want to remove the date from database but i want just remove the rows of datagridview for another query